# Clickhouse moving average

Tags: moving-average, clickhouse

Input:
Clickhouse

Table A
business_dttm (datetime)
amount (float)

I need to calculate moving sum for 15 minutes (or for last 3 records) on each business_dttm

For example

```
amount business_dttm     moving sum
0.3 2018-11-19 13:00:00  
0.3 2018-11-19 13:05:00
0.4 2018-11-19 13:10:00  1
0.5 2018-11-19 13:15:00  1.2
0.6 2018-11-19 13:15:00  1.5
0.7 2018-11-19 13:20:00  1.8
0.8 2018-11-19 13:25:00  2.1
0.9 2018-11-19 13:25:00  2.4
0.5 2018-11-19 13:30:00  2.2
```

Unfortunately we haven't window functions and join without equal conditions in Clickhouse

How can i do it without cross join and where condition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the window size is countably small, you can do something like this

```
SELECT
    sum(window.2) AS amount,
    max(dttm) AS business_dttm,
    sum(amt) AS moving_sum
FROM
(
    SELECT
        arrayJoin([(rowNumberInAllBlocks(), amount), (rowNumberInAllBlocks() + 1, 0), (rowNumberInAllBlocks() + 2, 0)]) AS window,
        amount AS amt,
        business_dttm AS dttm
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            amount,
            business_dttm
        FROM A
        ORDER BY business_dttm
    )
)
GROUP BY window.1
HAVING count() = 3
ORDER BY window.1;
```

The first two rows are ignored as ClickHouse doesn't collapse aggregates into null. You can prepend them later.

## Update:

It's still possible to compute moving sum for arbitrary window sizes. Tune the `window_size` as you want (3 for this example).

```
-- Note, rowNumberInAllBlocks is incorrect if declared inside with block due to being stateful
WITH
    (
        SELECT arrayCumSum(groupArray(amount))
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                amount
            FROM A
            ORDER BY business_dttm
        )
    ) AS arr,
    3 AS window_size
SELECT
    amount,
    business_dttm,
    if(rowNumberInAllBlocks() + 1 < window_size, NULL, arr[rowNumberInAllBlocks() + 1] - arr[rowNumberInAllBlocks() + 1 - window_size]) AS moving_sum
FROM
(
    SELECT
        amount,
        business_dttm
    FROM A
    ORDER BY business_dttm
)
```

Or this variant

```
SELECT
    amount,
    business_dttm,
    moving_sum
FROM
(
    WITH 3 AS window_size
    SELECT
        groupArray(amount) AS amount_arr,
        groupArray(business_dttm) AS business_dttm_arr,
        arrayCumSum(amount_arr) AS amount_cum_arr,
        arrayMap(i -> if(i < window_size, NULL, amount_cum_arr[i] - amount_cum_arr[(i - window_size)]), arrayEnumerate(amount_cum_arr)) AS moving_sum_arr
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM A
        ORDER BY business_dttm ASC
    )
)
ARRAY JOIN
    amount_arr AS amount,
    business_dttm_arr AS business_dttm,
    moving_sum_arr AS moving_sum
```

Fair warning, both approaches are far from optimal, but it exhibits the unique power of ClickHouse beyond SQL.

Comment: Unfortunately, window size ~ 10000 rows

Comment: Thanks for answer, but 1 moment. I was talking about Moving Sum, Not Cumulative Sum. Is it real to do it for Moving Sum?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [version 21.4](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/window-functions/) added the *full* support of window-functions. At this moment it was marked as an *experimental feature*.

```sql
SELECT
    amount,
    business_dttm,
    sum(amount) OVER (ORDER BY business_dttm ASC ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sum
FROM (
    SELECT data.1 AS amount, toDateTime(data.2) AS business_dttm
    FROM (
        SELECT arrayJoin([
            (0.3, '2018-11-19 13:00:00'),  
            (0.3, '2018-11-19 13:05:00'),
            (0.4, '2018-11-19 13:10:00'),
            (0.5, '2018-11-19 13:15:00'),
            (0.6, '2018-11-19 13:15:00'),
            (0.7, '2018-11-19 13:20:00'),
            (0.8, '2018-11-19 13:25:00'),
            (0.9, '2018-11-19 13:25:00'),
            (0.5, '2018-11-19 13:30:00')]) data)
    )
SETTINGS allow_experimental_window_functions = 1

/*
┌─amount─┬───────business_dttm─┬────────────────sum─┐
│    0.3 │ 2018-11-19 13:00:00 │                0.3 │
│    0.3 │ 2018-11-19 13:05:00 │                0.6 │
│    0.4 │ 2018-11-19 13:10:00 │                  1 │
│    0.5 │ 2018-11-19 13:15:00 │                1.2 │
│    0.6 │ 2018-11-19 13:15:00 │                1.5 │
│    0.7 │ 2018-11-19 13:20:00 │                1.8 │
│    0.8 │ 2018-11-19 13:25:00 │ 2.0999999999999996 │
│    0.9 │ 2018-11-19 13:25:00 │                2.4 │
│    0.5 │ 2018-11-19 13:30:00 │                2.2 │
└────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────────────┘
*/
```

See https://altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-window-functions-current-state-of-the-art.